# Unable to connect GitHub enterprise into TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, github-enterprise

We would like to connect TFS2017 to out GitHub for Enterprise.

- Added a new Service endpoint to "External Git"
- Configured it using my ghe username and a personal access token
- Added a new build definition
- Selected external git, and the service just configured
- Entered name of repository (no dropdown, tried various formats including the full
  https://ghe.mycompany.com/myUsername/myTestRepository.git)
- Triggered a new build

We get an error when we try to clone. The error occurs in "Get sources" step (1_Get_sources.txt)

```
2016-11-21T13:31:20.4836373Z Syncing repository: https://ghe.mycompany.com/********/myTestRepository.git (Git)
2016-11-21T13:31:20.5326404Z Starting clone
2016-11-21T13:31:21.0286690Z ##[error]LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: Request failed with status code: 404
2016-11-21T13:31:21.0296729Z ##[error]   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
2016-11-21T13:31:21.0306726Z ##[error]   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions& opts)
2016-11-21T13:31:21.0316723Z ##[error]   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options)
2016-11-21T13:31:21.0336678Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.CloneRepository(String repositoryPath, Uri repositoryUrl, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, String username, String password)
2016-11-21T13:31:21.0346735Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.SyncRepository(Uri repositoryUrl, String rootPath, Boolean cleanRepository, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, String sourceVersion, String username, String password)
2016-11-21T13:31:21.0356736Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.SyncRepository(ITaskEndpoint endpoint, String rootPath, Boolean cleanRepository, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, String sourceVersion)
2016-11-21T13:31:21.0366732Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.SyncAndCheckout(Boolean cleanRepository, String sourceBranch, String sourceVersion, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2016-11-21T13:31:21.0376729Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Plugin.Build.GitSourceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<PrepareRepositoryAsync>b__0()
```

Localy (on the TFS server) we're able to clone using powershell, and executing a script in a build step let us verify that the same proxy settings are used.

Below are some more debug from the _diag folder

```
    11:35:23.072987 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = af970025-e4bc-4692-a708-bbe734745370, message = Syncing repository: https://ghe.mycompany.com/********/myTestRepository.git (Git))
11:35:23.076124 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = af970025-e4bc-4692-a708-bbe734745370, message = repository url=https://ghe.mycompany.com/api/v3)
11:35:23.078235 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = af970025-e4bc-4692-a708-bbe734745370, message = checkoutSubmodules=False)
11:35:23.087627 Syncing and checking out sources.
11:35:23.087627 rootPath=C:\TfsBuildAgents\Agent-smi-build01\_work\22\s
11:35:23.087627 cleanRepository=True
11:35:23.087627 sourceBranch=master
11:35:23.087627 sourceVersion=
11:35:23.088628 sourcesToBuild=refs/remotes/origin/master
11:35:23.092875 Checking if the repo on disk matches the expected repository URL.
11:35:23.092875 gitRepoFolder=C:\TfsBuildAgents\Agent-smi-build01\_work\22\s
11:35:23.092875 expectedRepositoryUrl=https://ghe.mycompany.com/api/v3
11:35:23.120701 Unable to determine whether the existing repo matches. Suppressing the exception and treating the repo as if it doesn't match. For verbose purposes only, the exception is: LibGit2Sharp.RepositoryNotFoundException: Path 'C:\TfsBuildAgents\Agent-smi-build01\_work\22\s' doesn't point at a valid Git repository or workdir.
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_open(String path)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository..ctor(String path, RepositoryOptions options, RepositoryRequiredParameter requiredParameter)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.IsExpectedRepository(String gitRepoFolder, Uri expectedRepositoryUrl)
11:35:23.127765 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = af970025-e4bc-4692-a708-bbe734745370, message = Starting clone)
11:35:23.133909 Process logging event with task handler.
11:35:23.613344 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:35:23.615482 LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: Request failed with status code: 404

11:35:23.615482    at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)

11:35:23.615482    at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions& opts)

11:35:23.615482    at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options)

11:35:23.615482    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.CloneRepository(String repositoryPath, Uri repositoryUrl, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, String username, String password)

11:35:23.615482    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.SyncRepository(Uri repositoryUrl, String rootPath, Boolean cleanRepository, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, String sourceVersion, String username, String password)

11:35:23.616553    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.SyncRepository(ITaskEndpoint endpoint, String rootPath, Boolean cleanRepository, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, String sourceVersion)

11:35:23.616553    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.SyncAndCheckout(Boolean cleanRepository, String sourceBranch, String sourceVersion, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

11:35:23.616553    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Plugin.Build.GitSourceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<PrepareRepositoryAsync>b__0()
11:35:23.616553    at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)

11:35:23.616553    at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions& opts)

11:35:23.616553    at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options)

11:35:23.616553    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.CloneRepository(String repositoryPath, Uri repositoryUrl, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, String username, String password)

11:35:23.616553    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.SyncRepository(Uri repositoryUrl, String rootPath, Boolean cleanRepository, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, String sourceVersion, String username, String password)

11:35:23.616553    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.SyncRepository(ITaskEndpoint endpoint, String rootPath, Boolean cleanRepository, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, String sourceVersion)

11:35:23.616553    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.SyncAndCheckout(Boolean cleanRepository, String sourceBranch, String sourceVersion, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

11:35:23.616553    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Plugin.Build.GitSourceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<PrepareRepositoryAsync>b__0()
11:35:23.617555 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:35:23.618654 Process logging event with task handler.
11:35:23.623821 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = af970025-e4bc-4692-a708-bbe734745370, message = ##[error]LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: Request failed with status code: 404)
11:35:23.624910 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = af970025-e4bc-4692-a708-bbe734745370, message = ##[error]   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result))
11:35:23.625909 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = af970025-e4bc-4692-a708-bbe734745370, message = ##[error]   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions& opts))
11:35:23.626974 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = af970025-e4bc-4692-a708-bbe734745370, message = ##[error]   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options))
11:35:23.627973 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = af970025-e4bc-4692-a708-bbe734745370, message = ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.CloneRepository(String repositoryPath, Uri repositoryUrl, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, String username, String password))
11:35:23.629042 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = af970025-e4bc-4692-a708-bbe734745370, message = ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.SyncRepository(Uri repositoryUrl, String rootPath, Boolean cleanRepository, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, String sourceVersion, String username, String password))
11:35:23.630112 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = af970025-e4bc-4692-a708-bbe734745370, message = ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.SyncRepository(ITaskEndpoint endpoint, String rootPath, Boolean cleanRepository, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, String sourceVersion))
11:35:23.631180 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = af970025-e4bc-4692-a708-bbe734745370, message = ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.GitHelper.SyncAndCheckout(Boolean cleanRepository, String sourceBranch, String sourceVersion, Boolean checkoutSubmodules, CancellationToken cancellationToken))
11:35:23.632188 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = af970025-e4bc-4692-a708-bbe734745370, message = ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Plugin.Build.GitSourceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<PrepareRepositoryAsync>b__0())
11:35:23.634183 Process logging event with task handler.
11:35:23.638350 BaseLogger.LogStatus(scope.JobId = af970025-e4bc-4692-a708-bbe734745370, scope.TimelineRecordId = 2fd7ca75-f01d-4906-bf39-7c8d66a1df7f, record.Name = )
11:35:23.649716 BaseLogger.LogAttachment(scope.JobId = af970025-e4bc-4692-a708-bbe734745370, type = DistributedTask.Core.Log, name = Get sources, path = C:\TfsBuildAgents\Agent-smi-build01\_diag\w7ac045c8-3285-4be2-b993-b542da560c11.log)
11:35:23.658368 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:35:23.660442 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Common.AgentExecutionTerminationException: Prepare repository failed with exception. ---> LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: Request failed with status code: 404
```

Any idea how to debug this, or what we might try?

Comment: According to the error info it's something more like the url error? Did you have any proxy of your network?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Thanks for looking into this. When we do a git config --get http.proxy in powershell on the TFS server, and when we add a custom script to the build that prints out the proxy, they are both set to the same (correct value) - Maybe TFS git proxy is configured somewhere else?

Comment: You mentioned that "the same proxy settings are used (none)". Do you mean you didn't use any proxy or the http.proxy you get is "none"?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT sorry, error in the question. There is a proxy, and based on the git config commands, it looks like it set correctly. I'll update my question.

Comment: When you check the git config on the build server are you checking it with the account you're running the build agent under?

Comment: Yes. I even switched the TFS to run under my account

Comment: Can you set your build agent to run behind a proxy via this link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows#run-the-agent-behind-a-web-proxy and then try again?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Thanks for looking into this. Added proxy file in root dir, and restarted agent service, no change, got the same 404. Are there other logs I could provide?

Comment: Looks like you're using the 1.x agent, try installing the new 2.x agent, it uses git.exe to communicate to the external server, likely that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/repository?view=vsts) page you can't connect to Github Enterprise using TFS 2017. Please let me know if this has changed as I'd love to be able to do this!